# Wordpress Content Box not formatting correctly

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Does anyone else have this problem? When I am formatting things in the GUI in wordpress it looks great until I save the changes and view the page. Is this an issue with the style sheet?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this to superuser.com .. unless you can explain how you are trying to modify (not simply use) wordpress in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with the stylesheets - WordPress uses TinyMCE for its editor, and TinyMCE uses its own stylesheet.  When you publish the post or page, your site uses its own stylesheet, so your content renders differently.

To get around this, you'll need to dig into the TinyMCE plugin and change its configuration to use the stylesheet from your theme, or one similar to it.

Comment: This has been a great help! Thank you for the help.